# $\mathbb{Q}$ divisors on a concrete toric variety: contradiction

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry

I got a contradiction. Help me to understand it.
It is about answer by Sándor Kovács of a question
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55526/example-of-a-variety-with-k-x-mathbb-q-cartier-but-not-cartier

Kovács gave an example $X$. Basically this $X$ is a toric variety. It is not hard to calculate class group of $X$. For any toric variety class group is generated by tor-invariant divisors. For $X$ there are three such divisors. Set theoretically they are defined by equations $x^2=0$, $y^2=0$ and $z^2=0$. But those functions have zero of order two on corresponding divisors. So it is better to write

$$D_1 = \frac{1}{2} div( x^2 )$$
$$D_2 = \frac{1}{2} div( y^2 )$$
$$D_3 = \frac{1}{2} div( z^2 )$$

Relations between these divisors are generated by monomials.
$$D_1 + D_2 = div (xy) = 0$$
$$2 D_3 = div(z^2) = 0$$
$$ \dots $$

Relations are as follows $D_1 + D_2$, $D_2 + D_3$, $D_3 + D_1$, $2D_1$, $2D_2$, $2D_3$.

Evidently the class group which is generated by $D_1$, $D_2$ and $D_3$ modulo relations is just $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$. After tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ it becomes 0.

So the $K_X$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$ divisor which is just zero. But $\pi^* K_X$ is not zero as a $\mathbb{Q}$ divisor (it follows from Kovács calculations).

Question: What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there was a tiny mistake in my answer, although it did not change anything. The degree of $V$ is $4$, not $2$, but as you point out the calculation still leads to getting $\dfrac 12 E$.

Furthermore, since you calculated that $K_X$ generates the class group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, it shows the original claim that $K_X$ is not Cartier, but $2K_X$ is.

For the record, $\dfrac 12E$ is **not** integral despite any calculation. You can say that $E$ is linearly equivalent to twice an integral divisor, but that is not the same. One has to be careful distinguishing between *divisors* and *divisor classes*!

Comment: Sorry but your answer is still not correct. $E^2 = - 2 L$. It is a general fact: if you consider zero section $Z$ in total space of a line bundle $\mathcal{O}(D)$ then $Z^2 =D$.

Comment: You are right, it is $-2L$. But that just means that my original calculation was correct. :)

Comment: Calculation was correct. But it does not imply that $K_X$ is not Cartier.

Comment: Actually it does. I will add some stuff to the answer so you can see it.

Comment: I read your edits. Generally there are some problems with pull back of Weil divisors.  I even found your post about it here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16888/when-do-divisors-pull-back . Why this problems do not arise in this case?

Comment: There is no pull-back of Weil divisor in this answer. In some sense that's the point. Look at what I wrote about $\mathbb Q$-Cartier divisors in the answer you are linking.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand your point, but I think, that your post is still a bit confusing. Canonical class is not a divisor, it is class of linear equivalence of divisors. Assume, that $K_X$ is Cartier. You fix a representer of $K_X$. Then you choose a representer of $K_Y$ such that the representer of $K_Y$ minus $\pi^*$ of the representer of $K_X$ is equal to $aE$ (not just linear equivalent, but equal on the level of cycles). Finally you count $a = \frac{1}{2}$. And this proof that one of this representatives was not integer. But we choose integer representatives, contradiction.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that what I wrote was confusing. I used the customary language. What you write here is indeed the argument, which I did not include until you asked, because this is standard in this area, but of course if you are new to the area, then you may not have seen it. As I said in the answer above, $\dfrac 12 E$ is not integral even if it is $\mathbb Q$-linearly equivalent to an integral divisor. In other words, here as in the "when-do-divisors-pull-back" answer, it is important to distinguish between divisors and divisor classes. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Point one.** $K_X$ is indeed $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier but not Cartier. I calculated class group (see my question). It is $ \mathbb{Z}  / 2  \mathbb{Z} $. $K_X$ represents the nontrivial element of class group. To see this we will construct an explicit section $\omega$, which equals zero precisely on divisor $D_1$. Pull back of this section on $\mathbb{A}^3$ equals  $x dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$. If you want to be sure that this $\mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z}$ invariant form is indeed a form on $X$ you may write it in two chats:

$$\omega = \frac{d(x^2) d(y^2) d(z^2)}{8 yz}, \ \  \text{if} \ \  y \ne 0, \ \ z \ne 0$$

$$\omega = \frac{d(x^2) \wedge d(x y) \wedge d(x z)}{2x^2} \ \ \text{if} \ \  x \ne 0$$

To see that this two section matches on the overlap, one can take pull back on $\mathbb{A^3}$. To verify that zero locus of this section is indeed $D_1$ one should consider pull back on $\mathbb{A}^3$.

**Point two** The proof by Sándor Kovács is wrong (at least as far as I understand it). He claims that $K_Y = \pi^* K_X + \frac{1}{2} E$. And conclude that $\pi^* K_X = K_Y - \frac{1}{2} E$ is not integral (here is assumed that $\frac{1}{2} E$ is not linear equivalent to integral divisor)

The point is that $\pi^* K_X = 0$. And $\frac{1}{2} E$ is linear equivalent to integral.

Consider $\pi^* x^2 \in k[Y]$ $-$ pull back of $x^2 \in k[X]$.

It indeed has zero of order two on $\tilde{D}_1$ (which is proper transform of $D_1$). But also it has zero of order 1 on exceptional locus. To explain this I remind you that $Y$ is a total space of $\mathcal{O} (-2)$. One may treat $x^2$ as an element of $\Gamma ( \mathbb{P}^2, \mathcal{O}(2) )$. Section of dual bundle $\mathcal{E}^*$ always defines a function on total space of $\mathcal{E}$ which is linear on fibers (in our example $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{O}(-2)$). I leave it as an exercise to convinse yourself that this function coincides with $p^* x^2$. So $p^* x^2$ has zero of order one on exceptional locus (it is linear function on fibers, so it has zero of order one on zero section).

To conclude

$$div ( p^* x^2 ) = 2 \tilde{D}_1 + E$$

So $E$ is linear equivalent to $- 2 \tilde{D}_1$

Comment: Sándor Kovács proved everything correctly. I am sorry for my unfair accusations. He really works with actual divisors (not with divisor classes). I am thankful to Sándor Kovács for explanations.

Comment: My problem was purely psychological. You can do two thing things with group, generated by divisors: 1. quotient by rationality relation 2. tensor by $\mathbb{Q}$. You can do either of this things or both of them. For some reason I thought, that applying only the second thing is odd. But it actually helps in this example.